# SQL group - limit

Tags: sql, db2, limit

Sometimes finding the best way to communicate a 'problem' is as difficult as finding the solution... LOL but here goes...

I have a table with companies, I have a related table with some history for each company...
I want to return a query with a record set of the last 3 'history' entries per company...

so the recordset will look something like this...

```
company A
  history Az
  history Ay
  history Ax
company B
  history Bz
  history By
  history Bx
company C
  history Cz
  history Cy
  history Cx
```

The issue I'm running into is if I LIMIT 3 - with the joins being in there I JUST get the LAST 3 records of all the records, not the last 3 for EACH company...

Here's what I have last tried - but it's just pulling back ONE company, 3 records.. and that's it...(IBM DB2 9 - but the only thing that should affect is the syntax on the limit of 3..)

```
SELECT 
   C.CompanyName   
  ,H.*

FROM Companies C
JOIN CompanyTypes CT ON C.fkTypeID = CT.ID

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT   sCH.*
    FROM     CompanyHistory sCH
    ORDER BY sCH.DATE DESC 
    FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
) H ON H.fkCompanyID = C.ID 


WHERE CT.Type = 'bookstore'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW - changing my INNER JOIN - to LEFT OUTER JOIN returns ALL the companies, but only the top 3 records for the FIRST company, it ignores the history for the other companies...

Comment: The problem is that you're limiting the number of records from `CompanyHistory` to 3 *regardless of the company*. You need to move the 3 row limit outside of the join. I'll think about it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT C.CompanyName,H.*
FROM Companies C
JOIN CompanyTypes CT ON C.fkTypeID = CT.ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT   sCH.*
    FROM     CompanyHistory sCH    
    ORDER BY sCH.DATE DESC                   -- order desc so we can count
) H ON H.fkCompanyID = C.ID 
WHERE CT.Type = 'bookstore'
  and 3>(select count(*)                     -- at most 2 previous occurances
       from CompanyHistory ich
       where ich.fkCompanyID=C.ID            -- same company
          and datediff(d,ich.date,H.date)<0) -- but dates less than the row's date
```

Basically I'm counting the previous rows for each company, and dropping rows once we get past 2 (+the current row makes 3). You need to sort the `CompanyHistory` table by date desc for this to work.

You may need to replace `datediff` with the function for your SQL flavor, I only really know SQL Server.

Comment: thx Blindy - this works... date diff in DB2 looks like

 AND (days(H.TSPDATADATE) - days(ich.TSPDATADATE)) < 0

Comment: @jpmyob, I don't think `days` is right, it returns the day of month, so subtracting dates in sequential months will return the opposite result.

Comment: Blindy wins... at least as far as access plans and efficiencies goes... Tom's is more graceful looking - and the access plan looks better but here are the figures..

Comment: TOM's SQL 
1,134.78 Timerons (IBS resource/load estimate unit of measure)
62,775,280 instructions
153.83 I/Os

BLINDY's SQL
153.43 timerons
4,773,045 instructions
26.56 I/Os

I just started using access plans to evaluate my queries - so I'll cop to NOT KNOWING if they are "real" indicators of the efficiency of a query - but just accounting for instructions and IOs - I'd have to say the order of magnitude difference would yield a performance hit in a busy environment...

if there are some DBAs out there that can lend some light on that subject please edify me.

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like DB2 supports a ROW_NUMBER() with an OVER clause. I'm taking a guess at the syntax, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT
    CompanyName,
    SomeColumn
FROM (
    SELECT
        C.CompanyName,
        H.SomeColumn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.ID ORDER BY CH.DATE DESC)
    FROM
        Companies C
    INNER JOIN CompanyTypes CT ON C.fkTypeID = CT.ID
    INNER JOIN CompanyHistory CH ON CH.fkCompanyID = C.ID
) AS SQ
```

Comment: Thx Tom - this 'seems' more economical than Blindy's but I cant get the syntax to work - I'll keep at it and try to do a compare in an action plan to see about efficiency...

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get it to work. If there's a problem with my syntax (I don't use DB2), please let me know so that I can fix it for people who stumble on this answer in the future.